# Retrieve URLs from website tables

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

I'm trying to save table data from a website by using IMPORTXML and IMPORTHTML. These tables include text/numeric data, which I can retrieve with no problems, and hyperlinks wich I cannot retrieve. The formulas IMPORTXML and IMPORTHTML only allow me to save the link titles (but not the URL)

=IMPORTHTML("https://www.cmfchile.cl/institucional/inc/dictamenes.php?aa=2021", "table", 1)
=importxml("https://www.cmfchile.cl/institucional/inc/dictamenes.php?aa=2021", "//td")

I'm unsure whether a different formula is needed or just an additional element to retrieve the @href content.

This is one page of the website I'm working at:

https://www.cmfchile.cl/institucional/inc/dictamenes.php?aa=2021

The code appears as follows:

[image]